# Help with jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, menu

Html:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2
        <ul>
            <li class="submenu">something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').show().addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('ul').hide().removeClass('active');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mXTzy/

Now if  `.submenu` is being shown, I want the parent `li` to have the class `active` (and removed on mouseout).

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured:

```
$('#menu > li:has(.submenu)').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').children('ul').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active').children('ul').hide();    
});
```

.. a bit ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

idk if this will help you or not, but...

1. try use :contains selector (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)
2. you can use toggleClass (
       http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ )

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mXTzy/5/)

```js
$('#menu > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('ul').hide();  
   $(this).removeClass('active');  
});
```

```css
#meun li { float: left; }
#menu li a { float; left; padding:10px; }
#menu li ul { display: none; }
#menu li.active  { background:#dd0; }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2
        <ul>
            <li class="submenu">something</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```